# Position the Striped Right Arrow assigned with a macro

Tags: excel, vba

Let say I have a object: "Striped Right Arrow 2".

I want to create a macro which will position the object "Striped Right Arrow 2". In my macro I have a variable "n".

The following code works (it will position my object to the cell A26, for example with n = 6):

```
sub mymacro

n=6
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Striped Right Arrow 2")).Top = Range("A" & 2 * n + 10).Top
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Striped Right Arrow 2")).Left = Range("A" & 2 * n + 10).Left

end sub
```

However, now I want to position my object not only to the first cell (column A), but a column with variable, for example I want to position my object to Cells(2*n+10, n+5), I tried and the following code does not work:

```
sub mymacro

n=6
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Striped Right Arrow 2")).Top = Cells(2*n+10, n+5).Top
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Striped Right Arrow 2")).Left = Cells(2*n+10, n+5).Left

end sub
```

Can you correct my code?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens? Does it position to a wrong place? Does it not move it at all? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Stop the after `n = 6` and type this into the Immediate Window: `? Cells(2*n+10, n+5).Address` and check that you referred to the right cell, and did not e.g. swap the row and column number.

Comment: It's better to avoid ActiveSheet because if you navigate to another sheet in Excel, your code won't work. Try e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Your second code aligns the shape to cell K22.  If n=6, than 2*n+10 = 22 and n+5 = 11, which is K22.  Your code is working as expected.  What cell would you like it to be aligned to?

Comment: I tried again and it works.